# How do I parse an xml file with commons Digester and have it populate a java.util.Date object?

Tags: java, apache-commons-digester

Sample XML.

```
<person>
  <name>Joe Dirt</name>
  <ssn>123-45-6789</ssn>
  <dob>07/04/1981</dob>
</person>
```

Sample Java Class

```
public class Person(){
  private String name;
  private String ssn;
  private java.util.Date dob;
.....
}
```

Sample Digester rules

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<digester-rules>
  <pattern value="message">
      <object-create-rule classname="Person" />
      <bean-property-setter-rule pattern="name" propertyname="name" />
      <bean-property-setter-rule pattern="ssn" propertyname="ssn" />
      <bean-property-setter-rule pattern="dob" propertyname="dob" />
 </pattern>
</digester-rules>
```

Comment: I've heard of Commons Digester but never actually bothered to check...you need XML that's 3 times longer than the original XML to define how to populate a simple Bean?? How is that supposed to be handy or useful at all??? What the...just...what...the...

Comment: @Esko: Digester is quite handy sometimes. I never used the XML interface though, as it's also possible (and easier) to build rules in code.

Comment: @Esko: it's easier to change a few rules if the xml structure changes than it is to re-implement your parser. Most of the time I use a Stax parser, I'm just giving the Digester a try. I may revert back to Stax if this doesn't work well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Should be able to register a DateConverter, and all should work:

```
import org.apache.commons.beanutils.Converter;

class MyDateConverter implements Converter {
    @Override
    public Object convert(Class clazz, Object value) {
        if (clazz.equals(Date.class)) {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            try {
                return sdf.parse((String) value);
            } catch (ParseException pe) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(pe);
            } catch (ClassCastException cce) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(cce);
            }
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expected Date class");
        }
    }
}

......

import org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConvertUtils;

@Test
public void testXmlRules() throws Exception {
    ConvertUtils.register(new MyDateConverter(), Date.class);
    Digester digester = DigesterLoader.createDigester(new InputSource(this
            .getClass().getResourceAsStream("rules.xml")));
    Person person = (Person) digester.parse(this.getClass()
            .getResourceAsStream("person.xml"));
    Assert.assertEquals("Joe Dirt", person.getName());
    Assert.assertEquals("123-45-6789", person.getSsn());
    Assert.assertEquals(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")
            .parse("07/04/1981"), person.getDob());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've once faced this question myself. I didn't find any standard way to do this. The best I came up with was this:

```
digester.addRule(ROOT + "/lastBuildDate", new Rule() {
  public void body(final String namespace, final String name, final String text) throws Exception {
    Message message = (Message) getDigester().peek();
    if (text == null || text.trim().equals("")) {
      message.setDate(new Date());
    } else {
      try {
        message.setDate(parseDate(text));
      } catch (final ParseException e) {
        Log.warn("failed to parse date: " + text, e);
        message.setDate(new Date());
      }
    }
  }
});

Date parseDate(String text) throws ParseException {
  // left as an exercise to the reader
}
```

I can't help with using custom rules from your digester XML as I've always preferred to build digesters programmatically.

As a workaround, you could create an additional setter in your Person class:

```
public void setDobAsString(String dob) throws ParseException {
    setDob(parseDate(dob));
}
```